# Relative URLs with S3FS module

Tags: 7, uri

So I found this answer on here on how to get relative URLs on my Drupal 7 site ([How do I modify Drupal so that ONLY relative URLs are used through the whole site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105932/how-do-i-modify-drupal-so-that-only-relative-urls-are-used-through-the-whole-sit?lq=1)), but it doesn't seem to work nicely with S3FS.

Is there a way to modify this hook to work with S3FS, or is there another way that I should be getting relative URLs that works with S3FS?